# How to mount ISO to VMWare guest OS?

Tags: vmware-server, disk-image

I'm new to VMWare (more familiar with VirtualBox).

I'm looking to add an ISO to a new Guest OS (Windows Server 2008). I would like to add the ISO as a CD-ROM drive so that the server 2008 instance will boot with the installation media and install the OS.

Of course, I am operating under the assumption that Guest OS installations operate in a similar way to VirtualBox, and could be dead wrong about that.

Anyone been through this before? I'd appreciate the help.

We're using VMWare Server 2.0.1 with VMWare Infrastructure Web Access 2.0.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you edit the virtual machine, then select the cd-rom device, you can set the option to "Use ISO" and select your ISO file from there.  If you also set the drive to connect at boot, it should automatically boot to the iso on the next restart.

Edit: There's more details + pictures at [this link](http://www.petri.co.il/use-iso-image-files-vmware.htm).